SQL.issue related to data loading and performance
The situation is as follows: When i run my SQL query with a WHERE clause, i get a specific range of data, and it returns results successfully. However, when you remove the WHERE clause and try to retrieve all the data, no data is returned, and the system gives an error. This is generally an issue related to data loading and performance.
Do you have any suggestions for a solution?
It works:
query.Append(" FROM SAB.TATP WHERE EmployeeNr BETWEEN 23 AND 35");

It is not working:
query.Append(" FROM SAB.TATP WHERE EmployeeNr BETWEEN 23 AND 987889"); 

I get an error when trying to fetch all the data.I am using ASP.NET Core with MVC in C#.

What does the error message say? Please [edit] the question to supply the error as text, not as a screen shot.

First of all, Taking WHOLE DATA never a good practice! Even for a test !!!!
Code Execution is not only consist data, here what is query (seems string but may be an extension etc.) is it ORM r someting else ?
Please, be more clear about exception/detail and runtime info !
